# kivy buildozer error: sh.CommandNotFound: ./download.sh

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy, buildozer

This is my first time using buildozer to convert a kivy project to android app and I am running into a problem. It may be just the way I've installed buildozer and its dependencies but I can't be certain. I'm running Linux Mint natively so all the tutorials that mention using a VM to get an instance of linux didn't pertain to me so I skipped it. I did already fix a problem with properly installing cython that was different than in a VM. Maybe my problem is another similar issue but I can't figure this one out. If there is a proper tutorial to follow for a native linux user that might be of some use.

In short, the error I'm running into says `sh.CommandNotFound: ./download.sh` after `Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a`

Here is the last bit of the log (full log running into the 30k character limit)

```
jacob@Jacob-Linux:~/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App$ buildozer android debug
.
.
.
[INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
[INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for hostpython3[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    hostpython3 already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding libbz2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    libbz2 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for libbz2[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    libbz2 already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    libffi has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for libffi[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    libffi already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding liblzma for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    liblzma has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    openssl has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/SDL2_image/external
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1297, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 730, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 497, in build_recipes
    recipe.prebuild_arch(arch)
  File "/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/sdl2_image/__init__.py", line 21, in prebuild_arch
    shprint(sh.Command("./download.sh"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.3-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1310, in __init__
    raise CommandNotFound(path)
sh.CommandNotFound: ./download.sh
# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=BTR', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,pandas,os,time,threading', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/Jacob-Linux:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1246,unix/Jacob-Linux:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1246'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'cinnamon'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1329'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/jacob/Desktop/Projects/BT_Relay_App'
#     LOGNAME = 'jacob'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'cinnamon'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/jacob/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/jacob'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     INSIDE_NEMO_PYTHON = ''
#     HOME = '/home/jacob'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'X-Cinnamon'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/29be4d4e_5275_4a01_a316_8e1f73e6d205'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING = '1'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'jacob'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.2949'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c1'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     GTK3_MODULES = 'xapp-gtk3-module'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/gnome:/usr/share/cinnamon:/home/jacob/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share'
#     PATH = '/home/jacob/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/jacob/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'cinnamon'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/jacob/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/jacob/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/jacob/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '30'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Try  a basic sh command `sh something`  --  You SHOULD get back `sh: 0: Can't open something` -- If you get Command not found, you need to make sure `sh` command can reach your `shell` for executing.  You can look in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` to see if the sh command even exists ..

Comment: it does say `sh: 0: Can't open something`

Comment: yea it looks like its not in either `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. what exactly does that mean I have to do?

Comment: Well it looks like you're able to sh .. I would suggest looking for `./download.sh` in the directory the program "thinks" it's in .. That file may not exist ..  Or there may be issues inside of the file ..   Some manual debugging is probably going to have to be done on your part.

Comment: Well I just followed a different tutorial this time for buildozer setup with slightly different steps and I seem to have solved all my problems